# application error on heroku - works fine on localhost

Tags: jquery, css, heroku, sails.js, ejs

I have been developing an app - can be found here : https://github.com/yhattav/Friendli

I tried to load it into heroku to test it from another device but i cannot open it.

I have added mLab MongoDB to the resources.

Still, the consol doesnt really say why it crashed:
2016-04-16T21:16:23.392068+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=yhattav-friendly.herokuapp.com request_id=5f3597f5-cf8f-4be2-9e95-c243ebbd9eb1 fwd="94.230.84.121" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Thanks for your help!
Yonatan.

Answer (score 2):

In your terminal after you push to heroku, you can enter `heroku logs` That will show you any sort of error that happened while trying to deploy.

Comment: You can also see logs also on heroku.com. On the top right menu. Check to see what's the specific error there

Comment: What is my "terminal"?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, sails crashed during lift because 503 is indicating unavailability.

I recommend using the heroku addon papertrail (for free) to view the logs.

How do start sails on heroku - with pm2 or something similar?

Comment: I am not sure about you question. I just put it in a repo in github and then I used the repo though heroku. these are the logs that papertrail got me: https://github.com/yhattav/Friendli/blob/master/Heroku%20log%20erors

Comment: and this is within papertrail : https://papertrailapp.com/systems/yhattav-friendly/events?r=658380818695409664-658452137793376256

Comment: It might be related to your connections.js file. Can you send the configuration you're using for your mongo connection?

Comment: In addition to Guy Sopher's question, what's in your Procfile?
Also, have you set up a remote database (e.g. mLab, etc.)? I guess you are trying to reach your db on localhost which works from localhost, but not from heroku obvs. Heroku error R10 is indicating this a bit: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r10-boot-timeout